# Popup from multiple services

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, popup, dojo

I am trying to have one infowindow/popup show from multiple services. I have successfully added the second service to my code, however, only 1 result will display.

Ex. if I am at full scale, only the zoning layer is returned in the popup. If I zoom in, only the parcel layer is returned in the popup.

How can I get both services to show within the popup? Additionally, how can I make it so only the visible layers show within the popup?

Here is the code I have edited:

```
dojo.require("esri.dijit.Popup"); //Infowindow

var identifyTask,identifyParams;    

  function mapReady(map){

   dojo.connect(map,"onClick",executeIdentifyTask);

   //create identify tasks and setup parameters 
   identifyTaskZoning = new esri.tasks.IdentifyTask("https://www.marioncountyfl.org/arcgis/rest/services/Dynamic/Zoning/MapServer");
   identifyTaskParcels = new esri.tasks.IdentifyTask("https://www.marioncountyfl.org/arcgis/rest/services/Dynamic/Parcels/MapServer");

        //Set Zoning Parameters
   identifyParamsZoning = new esri.tasks.IdentifyParameters();
   identifyParamsZoning.tolerance = 7;
   identifyParamsZoning.returnGeometry = true;
   identifyParamsZoning.layerIds = [0,1,2,3,4];
   identifyParamsZoning.layerOption = esri.tasks.IdentifyParameters.LAYER_OPTION_VISIBLE;
   identifyParamsZoning.width  = map.width;
   identifyParamsZoning.height = map.height;
        //Set Parcel Parameters
   identifyParamsParcels = new esri.tasks.IdentifyParameters();
   identifyParamsParcels.tolerance = 15;
   identifyParamsParcels.returnGeometry = true;
   identifyParamsParcels.layerIds = [0,1,2,3,4];
   identifyParamsParcels.layerOption = esri.tasks.IdentifyParameters.LAYER_OPTION_VISIBLE;
   identifyParamsParcels.width  = map.width;
   identifyParamsParcels.height = map.height;

   //resize the map when the browser resizes
   dojo.connect(dijit.byId('map'), 'resize', map,map.resize);
  };

  function executeIdentifyTask(evt){
 identifyParamsParcels.geometry = evt.mapPoint;
 identifyParamsParcels.mapExtent = map.extent;
 var deferred = identifyTaskParcels.execute(identifyParamsParcels);
 deferred.addCallback(function(response){
   if (response.length > 0) {
//         console.log(response.length)
//         response is an array of identify result objects    
//         Let's return an array of features.
    return dojo.map(response, function(result){
      var feature = result.feature;
      feature.attributes.layerName = result.layerName;
      if(result.layerName === 'TaxParcel'){
          console.log(feature.attributes.NAME);
          var template = new esri.dijit.PopupTemplate({
                        title:"Parcels",
                        description:"<b>Parcel ID:</b> {Parcel Identification Number} <br/> <b>Address:</b> {Site Address}"
                        });
          feature.setInfoTemplate(template);
        }

            return feature;
    });
    }
  else {
      identifyParamsZoning.geometry = evt.mapPoint;
      identifyParamsZoning.mapExtent = map.extent;
      var deferred = identifyTaskZoning.execute(identifyParamsZoning);
      deferred.addCallback(function(response){
        // response is an array of identify result objects    
        // Let's return an array of features.
        return dojo.map(response, function(result){
          var feature = result.feature;
          feature.attributes.layerName = result.layerName;
        if(result.layerName === 'Zoning Classifications'){
          console.log(feature.attributes.NAME);
          var template = new esri.dijit.PopupTemplate({
                        title:"Zoning",
                        description:"<b>Zoning:</b> {Zoning Classification} <br/> <b>Description:</b> {Zoning Description}"
                        });
          feature.setInfoTemplate(template);
        }
        else if (result.layerName === 'Assisted Living Facilities'){
          var template = new esri.dijit.PopupTemplate({
                        title:"Assisted Living Facilities",
                        description:"<b>Parcel ID:</b> {Parcel} <br/> <b>Applicant:</b> {BusinessApplicantName} <br/> <b>No. of Residents</b> {NbrResidents}"
                        });
          feature.setInfoTemplate(template);
        }
                    else if (result.layerName === 'Family Divisions'){
          var template = new esri.dijit.PopupTemplate({
                        title:"Family Divisions",
                        description:"<b>Parcel ID:</b> {Parcel} <br/> <b>Project Number:</b> {project_nbr} </br> <b>Status:</b> {Status}"
                        });
          feature.setInfoTemplate(template);
        }
                    else if (result.layerName === 'Policy 120'){
          var template = new esri.dijit.PopupTemplate({
                        title:"Policy 120",
                        description:"<b>Parcel ID:</b> {Parcel} <br/> <b>Business Name:</b> {BusinessName} </br> <b>Date of Letter:</b> {DateOfLetter}"
                        });
          feature.setInfoTemplate(template);
        }
                    else if (result.layerName === 'Zoning Changes'){
          var template = new esri.dijit.PopupTemplate({
                        title:"Zoning Changes",
                        description:"<b>Parcel ID:</b> {Parcel} <br/> <b>Request Number:</b> {REQUEST_NBR} </br> <b>Property Owner:</b> {PROPERTY_OWNER}"
                        });
          feature.setInfoTemplate(template);
        }
        return feature;
        });
      });
  };
    map.infoWindow.setFeatures([deferred]);
    map.infoWindow.show(evt.mapPoint);          
  });
    map.infoWindow.setFeatures([deferred]);
    map.infoWindow.show(evt.mapPoint);      
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this blog entry I wrote about identifying multiple services with dojo DeferredList. It address only the visible layers. Once you have the result, you'll have to create a custom popup. http://www.spatialexception.org/posts/arcgis-javascript-identifytask-returns-scale-dependent-layers

**Edit**
I'm using jqueryUI to create widgets so I'm not sure if you want to use this, but here's the way I'm displaying. It's not really a popup, but more like an ArcMap Identify. The code needs to be cleaned up, e.g. get the html out of the javascript, but here it is...

```
<!-- html fragment -->

<!-- Use local custom theme copy of jQuery ui -->
<!-- http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Theming/API
To view and modify and re-download this theme, visit http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/?ffDefault=Verdana,%20Arial,%20sans-serif&fwDefault=normal&fsDefault=1.1em&cornerRadius=6px&bgColorHeader=444444&bgTextureHeader=03_highlight_soft.png&bgImgOpacityHeader=44&borderColorHeader=333333&fcHeader=ffffff&iconColorHeader=ffffff&bgColorContent=000000&bgTextureContent=14_loop.png&bgImgOpacityContent=25&borderColorContent=555555&fcContent=ffffff&iconColorContent=cccccc&bgColorDefault=222222&bgTextureDefault=03_highlight_soft.png&bgImgOpacityDefault=35&borderColorDefault=444444&fcDefault=eeeeee&iconColorDefault=cccccc&bgColorHover=003147&bgTextureHover=03_highlight_soft.png&bgImgOpacityHover=33&borderColorHover=0b93d5&fcHover=ffffff&iconColorHover=ffffff&bgColorActive=0972a5&bgTextureActive=04_highlight_hard.png&bgImgOpacityActive=20&borderColorActive=26b3f7&fcActive=ffffff&iconColorActive=222222&bgColorHighlight=eeeeee&bgTextureHighlight=03_highlight_soft.png&bgImgOpacityHighlight=80&borderColorHighlight=cccccc&fcHighlight=2e7db2&iconColorHighlight=4b8e0b&bgColorError=ffc73d&bgTextureError=02_glass.png&bgImgOpacityError=40&borderColorError=ffb73d&fcError=111111&iconColorError=a83300&bgColorOverlay=5c5c5c&bgTextureOverlay=01_flat.png&bgImgOpacityOverlay=50&opacityOverlay=80&bgColorShadow=cccccc&bgTextureShadow=01_flat.png&bgImgOpacityShadow=30&opacityShadow=60&thicknessShadow=7px&offsetTopShadow=-7px&offsetLeftShadow=-7px&cornerRadiusShadow=8px
-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom/js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js"></script>
<link href="js/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom/css/dark-hive/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<body>    
    <div id="dialogIdentify" title="Identify Features">
        <div id="accordionIdentify">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

//javascript fragment

//at some point open the dialog to start
('#dialogIdentify').dialog('open');

$('#dialogIdentify').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 320,
    height: 400,
    position: 'right',        
    open: function (event, ui) {
        startIdentify();
    },
    close: function (event, ui) {
        endIdentify();
    }
});

var identifyTask, identifyParams, symbol;
var identify_connect;
var resultsRefTemp, resultsOpTemp, numResultSets;

function startIdentify() {
    //$("#map_layers").css("cursor", "url(img/identify2.cur), crosshair");
    $("#accordionIdentify").append("<p>(Click on map to identify features)</p>");
    identify_connect = dojo.connect(map, "onClick", doIdentify);
}

function endIdentify() {
    //$("#map_layers").css("cursor", "auto");
    map.graphics.clear();
    $("#accordionIdentify").accordion("destroy");
    $("#accordionIdentify").empty();
    dojo.disconnect(identify_connect);
    $("#dialogIdentify").dialog("option", "position", ['right']);
    $('#accordionIdentify .identifyHL').off('click');
    identifyLayerKeyPrevious = undefined;
}

function executeIdentify(geom, serviceName, aLayerIds) {
    var identifyParams = new esri.tasks.IdentifyParameters(),
        identifyTask = new esri.tasks.IdentifyTask(serviceName);
    identifyParams.geometry = geom;
    identifyParams.mapExtent = map.extent;
    identifyParams.tolerance = 3;
    identifyParams.returnGeometry = true;
    identifyParams.layerIds = aLayerIds;
    //refers to default visible layers as defined on the server
    identifyParams.layerOption = esri.tasks.IdentifyParameters.LAYER_OPTION_ALL;
    identifyParams.width = map.width;
    identifyParams.height = map.height;
    return identifyTask.execute(identifyParams);
}

function doIdentify(evt) {
    var geom = evt.mapPoint,
        aLayersInScale,
        aDeferreds = [],
        deferredList,
        currentScale = map.getScale(),
        aVisibleSubLayers,
        aAGSDynMapServicesToIdentify = [referenceLayer, operationalLayer];

    map.graphics.clear();
    identifyLayerKeyPrevious = undefined;

    //loop thru dynamic services, then thru visible sublayers that are not group layers, then check within scale
    dojo.forEach(aAGSDynMapServicesToIdentify, function (agsDynMapService) {
        aVisibleSubLayers = agsDynMapService.visibleLayers;
        if (agsDynMapService.visible === true && aVisibleSubLayers.length !== 0 && aVisibleSubLayers[0] !== -1) {
            aLayersInScale = [];
            dojo.forEach(agsDynMapService.createDynamicLayerInfosFromLayerInfos(), function (dLayInfo) {
                if (dLayInfo.subLayerIds === null && dojo.indexOf(aVisibleSubLayers, dLayInfo.id) !== -1 &&
                        (dLayInfo.minScale === undefined || dLayInfo.minScale === 0 || currentScale <= dLayInfo.minScale) &&
                        (dLayInfo.maxScale === undefined || dLayInfo.maxScale === 0 || currentScale >= dLayInfo.maxScale)) {
                    aLayersInScale.push(dLayInfo.id);
                }
            });
            if (aLayersInScale.length > 0) {
                aDeferreds.push(executeIdentify(evt.mapPoint, agsDynMapService.url, aLayersInScale));
            }
        }
    });

    // create a deferred list to aggregate the state for all identify queries
    deferredList = new dojo.DeferredList(aDeferreds);
    deferredList.then(function (aIdentifyResults) {
        // "aIdentifyResults" is 2D array of results
        // array[n][0] boolean true or false, success or failure of individual call
        // array[n][1] is the array of identity results returned
        formatIdentifyResults(aIdentifyResults);
    });
}

function formatIdentifyResults(res) {
    var finalResults = [],
        shouldReturn = false;

    $("#accordionIdentify").accordion("destroy");
    $("#accordionIdentify").empty();

    $.each(res, function (k1, v1) {
        // array[n][0] indicates success or failure
        if (v1[0] === false) {
            $("#accordionIdentify").append("<p>An error occurred during the identify query.</p>");
            shouldReturn = true;
            return false; //only breaks loop
        }
        // array[n][1] is the array of identity results returned
        if (v1 !== undefined && v1[1].length > 0) {
            v1[1].reverse();
            finalResults = finalResults.concat(v1[1]);
        }
    });
    if (shouldReturn) {
        return;
    }
    if (finalResults.length === 0) {
        $("#accordionIdentify").append("<p>No results were found.</p>");
        return;
    }
    idResultsForHighlighting = finalResults;

    //build the accordian widget
    var lastPanel = 0;
    var isAnotherFeature = 0;
    var prevlayerName = finalResults[0].layerName;
    var innerHtml = "<h3><a href=\"#\">" + prevlayerName + "</a></h3><div>";
    $.each(finalResults, function (layerKey, layerValue) {
        if (prevlayerName === layerValue.layerName) { //layer has not changed
            if (isAnotherFeature > 0) {
                innerHtml = innerHtml + "<hr />"; //start another feature by drawing hr
            }
        }
        else { //layer has changed
            innerHtml = innerHtml + "</div>"; //close
            innerHtml = innerHtml + "<h3><a href='#'>" + layerValue.layerName + "</a></h3><div>"; //start new accordian fold
            isAnotherFeature = 0; //reset feature count for layer
            lastPanel++;
        }

        innerHtml = innerHtml + "<a id='" + layerKey + "' href='#' style='color: blue' class='identifyHL' >Highlight Feature</a></td>";
        //create table of attributes and values for feature
        innerHtml = innerHtml + "<table><tbody>";
        $.each(layerValue.feature.attributes, function (key, value) {
            innerHtml = innerHtml + "<tr><td>" + key + "</td><td>" + value + "</td></tr>";
        });
        innerHtml = innerHtml + "</tbody></table>";

        prevlayerName = layerValue.layerName; //check for layer change
        isAnotherFeature++;
    });
    innerHtml = innerHtml + "</div>";
    $("#accordionIdentify").append(innerHtml);
    $("#accordionIdentify").accordion({
        autoHeight: false,
        collapsible: true,
        active: lastPanel //activate:false has all h3's closed, activate:activatePanel opens last added h3
    });
    $("#accordionIdentify .identifyHL").on('click', function () {
        showFeature($(this).attr('id'));
    });
}

var idResultsForHighlighting;
var identifyLayerKeyPrevious;
var isIdentifyHighlighted = false;
function showFeature(identifyLayerKey) {
    map.graphics.clear();
    //this if statement makes the highlight link toggle, if feature already highlighted
    if (isIdentifyHighlighted === false || identifyLayerKeyPrevious === undefined || identifyLayerKeyPrevious !== identifyLayerKey) {
        var idResult = idResultsForHighlighting[identifyLayerKey];
        var symbol;
        if (idResult.geometryType === "esriGeometryPoint") {
            symbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol();
            symbol.setColor(new dojo.Color([0, 255, 255, 0.7]));
        }
        else if (idResult.geometryType === "esriGeometryPolygon") {
            symbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol();
            symbol.setColor(new dojo.Color([0, 255, 255, 0.7]));
        }
        else { //"esriGeometryPolyline" 
            symbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol();
            symbol.setColor(new dojo.Color([0, 255, 255, 0.7]));
        }
        idResult.feature.setSymbol(symbol);
        map.graphics.add(idResult.feature);
        isIdentifyHighlighted = true;
    }
    else {
        isIdentifyHighlighted = false;
    }
    identifyLayerKeyPrevious = identifyLayerKey;
}
```

Comment: so how does it work if I have more services than I want id'd? Example: 7 total services and only want to return results on 3.

Comment: In my code, you would just put the 3 in the following array where I have 2. 
aAGSDynMapServicesToIdentify = [referenceLayer, operationalLayer];

Comment: thanks for your help. I'm still learning the API, dojo, and javascript so please forgive my lack of understanding. I have taken your example and added my 3 services, but don't quite understand how to build the infowindow/popup to be unique to each service. Do you have a working sample that I might be able to look at to get a better idea of how to construct? Thanks again.

Comment: That blog entry is currently giving an error "Error establishing a database connection". I was hoping to see that as it could potentially help me with the same issue.

Comment: Yes, I need to reset the website, but I don't have the laptop that has the connection information I need. The deferredList is the heart of it, but it's changed in the current version of dojo -- so it would need to be revised anyway. Also, I see that I'm mixing jquery in there too, to make it more confusing. Sorry!