# Identify Tool for JS API similar to the tool in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, tools

As documented in my earlier questions, I am having trouble connecting multiple ArcGIS Server services to identifyTasks. Therefore, I'm wondering if there is a tool/process or if its possible to create a button or tool that mimics the identify process in ArcGIS Desktop, where I can select which layer/service I want to identify and then click a point on the map to get the results?

Comment: It'd be helpful to know what js framework your using, also this post is not as much an answer, but [why your asking the wrong question](http://mapbrief.com/2013/02/19/an-iconography-of-confusion-why-map-portals-dont-work-part-iv/)

Comment: good article, and fair critique, certainly not my preferred solution, but I'm up against a deadline of this Friday and its the only piece of my app that isn't working as requested. the app is written using ESRI JS API v3.2. Problem is I have 3 services with several layers that need to be identified, only if visible.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is set up a click event which captures where the user clicked and then iterate through the visible layers and returns features that intersect the click point.

on the esri documentation site they have [this sample](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jssamples/#sample/find_drilldown) which looks to be similar to what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am attempting to identify from multiple services(rest endpoints) and each service has at least 1 but potentially layer within it. My previous question is http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49275/popup-from-multiple-services but it doesn't seem to be working for me, so I've decided to attempt the portal.